# Write an AppleScript to combine multiple pdf pages in one pdf

Tags: applescript, javascript

I am designing a workflow in which multiple one page-long PDF files should be combined into a single PDF file using Folder Action Script.

If you have any script for that please share.

Comment: Automator has some pre-built functionality for this, might be easier than AppleScript.

Comment: I'm missing a real question as well as any research done by the OP here! Please show us your previous (failing?) attempts to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Patrix said try Automator..[image]

Comment: https://www.orbitsit.co.uk/2013/06/combining-pdfs-using-automator/